# Ibatis execute update sql on oracle, it is not working and no exceptions

Tags: java, oracle, ibatis

iBatis 2.3.0

```
int ret = getSqlMapClientTemplate.update("sql", params);

 <update id="sql">
 update mytable set chk=#chk# where id in 
 <dynamic>
        <iterate property="ids" open="(" close=")" conjunction=","> 
            #ids[]#
        </iterate>
    </dynamic>
</update>
```

So, 'ret' returns 0 rows updated.
Th ids' length is less than 20, and it did not work, no exceptions or errors are thrown. 
I don't think its a deadlock, since the program returns the result & does not hand waiting for the deadlock to time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest setting the log4j Level to a lower setting to see the SQL that is being executed against the database and what the parameters are that are passed into the statement...

```
  <logger name="org.springframework">
    <level value="INFO"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="com.ibatis">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="java.sql">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
  </logger>
```